# Change/filter markers from custom check boxes

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json

So I'm working on a map using leaflet and I want to use custom check boxes, not the default controls. I'm returning the correct json information when I check the boxes. I'm just not sure how to swap out the json reference and trigger marker refresh. Any thoughts would be welcome. The project can be seen here: https://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/PQvMqR?editors=1010

Basically what I'm asking is how do I swap out the original geoJSON for a reduced version on an external (outwith the map) click event.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a layergroup and add/remove data from your layer as you filter them. Look at the source code for http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html I have an initial load of the data, then from my radio buttons I add and remove the layers data as checked.